# How to check what child class a variable belongs to in an ArrayList with 2 child types of 1 parent?

Tags: java, arraylist

Sorry if the question is confusing. Here is an example:

There is an ArrayList containing data of type "Shape".

"Circle" and "Triangle" are both children of "Shape". Circle has method calculateRadius(). Triangle does not and cannot.

I would like to look through all shapes in the ArrayList and check the radius:

```
for(Shape s : shapeList)
{
    System.out.println(s.calculateRadius);
}
```

I understand this won't work, as neither shape nor triangle has this method. Is there a way to check if the shape in the list is a circle or triangle and then calculate the radius if the shape is a circle?

How list was defined and data was added:

```
ArrayList<shape> shapeList = new ArrayList<shape>;

...

Circle c = new Circle(a, b, c, radius);
Triangle t = new Triangle(a, b, c, type);
shapeList.add(c);
shapeList.add(t);
```

Comment: You *could* solve this by using instanceof, but that would be an ugly kludge. Better to use the Visitor design pattern if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep it simple, just type check before using;

```
for (Shape s : shapeList)
{
    if (s instanceof Circle)
    {
        System.out.println(((Circle) s).calculateRadius);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't used instanceof before, but that was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @J.Swann No problem at all. Please accept the answer if it worked out for you, so others don't spend time working on it